boxplot of raster and shapefile
This example code works
library(raster)
library(sp)
library(rgdal)
library(ggplot2)

# Create some sample raster data
raster_file <- raster(ncol=36, nrow=18)
raster_file[] <- 1:ncell(raster_file)
plot(raster_file)

#Create some sample polygons
cds1 <- rbind(c(-180,-20), c(-160,5), c(-60, 0), c(-160,-60), c(-180,-20))
cds2 <- rbind(c(80,0), c(100,60), c(120,0), c(120,-55), c(80,0)) 
shape_file <-        SpatialPolygons(list(Polygons(list(Polygon(cds1)), 1), 
                          Polygons(list(Polygon(cds2)), 2)))
plot(shape_file)


# Extract raster values within the shapefile extracted_values <- extract(raster_file, shape_file)


# Assuming the shapefile has multiple polygons and you want to create a boxplot for each 
data_list <-   lapply(1:length(extracted_values), function(i) {
  data.frame(value = extracted_values[[i]], polygon = i)
 })
data <- do.call(rbind, data_list)

# Create the boxplot
bp<-ggplot(data, aes(x = factor(polygon), y = value)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  labs(x = "Polygon", y = "Raster Values") +
  theme_minimal()
 bp

For my own dataset I encountered problems in reading in the polygons.
The error message comes in the boxplot function
Here may shape file
> # load shape file including all layers and print layers
> shape_file<-shapefile("C:/Users/.....BiogeoRegion.shp")
Warning message:
[vect] Z coordinates ignored 
> names(shape_file)
 [1] "RegionNumm" "RegionName" "Unterregio" "Unterreg_1" "ObjNummer"
"Version"    "Shape_Leng" "Shape_Area" "DERegionNa" "FRRegionNa"
[11] "ITRegionNa" "DEBioBedeu" "FRBioBedeu" "ITBioBedeu"
> str(shape_file)
Formal class 'SpatialPolygonsDataFrame' [package "sp"] with 5 slots
  ..@ data       :'data.frame': 12 obs. of  14 variables:
  .. ..$ RegionNumm: int [1:12] 1 2 2 2 2 3 3 4 5 5 ...
   .. ..$ RegionName: chr [1:12] "R1" "R2" "R2" "R2" ...
   .. ..$ Unterregio: int [1:12] 11 21 22 23 24 31 32 41 51 52 ...
   .. ..$ Unterreg_1: chr [1:12] "U11" "U21" "U22" "U23" ...
   .. ..$ ObjNummer : chr [1:12] "1" "2" "3" "4" ...
  .. ..$ Version   : chr [1:12] "2020/05/08" "2020/05/08" "2020/05/08"
 "2020/05/08" ...


> # select a specific raster file from a list 
> raster_file<-allrasters_pres[[1]]
> names(raster_file)
[1] "Andrena.barbilabris_glo_ensemble"
> 
> # Extract raster values within the shapefile extracted_values <- 
> extract(raster_file, shape_file)
> 
> 
> 
> # Assuming the shapefile has multiple polygons and you want to create 
 > a
 boxplot for each
 > data_list <- lapply(1:length(extracted_values), function(i) {
 +     data.frame(value = extracted_values[[i]], polygon = i)
 + })
> data <- do.call(rbind, data_list)

> names(data)
[1] "value"   "polygon"
> 
> # Create the boxplot
> bp<-ggplot(data, aes(x = factor(polygon), y = value)) +
 +     geom_boxplot() +
 +     labs(x = "Polygon", y = "Raster Values") +
 +     theme_minimal()
 > bp
 Error in UseMethod("depth") : 
 no applicable method for 'depth' applied to an object of class "NULL"
  In addition: Warning message:
Removed 452451 rows containing non-finite outside the scale range (`stat_boxplot()`). 
 >


Check your data object. Not just names/columns  but actual content. Note that from your included code it's not really clear what exactly was executed or if console output was later manually edited.. For example , was the actual expression   extract(raster_file, shape_file) (without assignment) or extracted_values <- extract(raster_file, shape_file)

If it doesn't have to be based on raster and sp packages, you might want to consider terra or sf + stars instead.
With copy-pastes from terra documentation it might look something like this:
library(terra)
#> terra 1.7.78
library(ggplot2)

# Load shp and raster from example files of terra
(v <- vect(system.file("ex/lux.shp", package="terra")))
#>  class       : SpatVector 
#>  geometry    : polygons 
#>  dimensions  : 12, 6  (geometries, attributes)
#>  extent      : 5.74414, 6.528252, 49.44781, 50.18162  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#>  source      : lux.shp
#>  coord. ref. : lon/lat WGS 84 (EPSG:4326) 
#>  names       :  ID_1   NAME_1  ID_2   NAME_2  AREA   POP
#>  type        : <num>    <chr> <num>    <chr> <num> <int>
#>  values      :     1 Diekirch     1 Clervaux   312 18081
#>                    1 Diekirch     2 Diekirch   218 32543
#>                    1 Diekirch     3  Redange   259 18664
(r <- rast(system.file("ex/elev.tif", package="terra")))
#> class       : SpatRaster 
#> dimensions  : 90, 95, 1  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
#> resolution  : 0.008333333, 0.008333333  (x, y)
#> extent      : 5.741667, 6.533333, 49.44167, 50.19167  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#> coord. ref. : lon/lat WGS 84 (EPSG:4326) 
#> source      : elev.tif 
#> name        : elevation 
#> min value   :       141 
#> max value   :       547
plot(r); plot(v, add = TRUE); text(v, labels = "NAME_2", col=c("white"))


# extract, include names from vector attributes
e <- extract(r,v)
e$NAME_2 <- v$NAME_2[e$ID]
str(e)
#> 'data.frame':    4606 obs. of  3 variables:
#>  $ ID       : num  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
#>  $ elevation: int  547 485 497 515 515 515 518 531 540 NA ...
#>  $ NAME_2   : chr  "Clervaux" "Clervaux" "Clervaux" "Clervaux" ...

# plot
ggplot(e, aes(x = NAME_2, y = elevation)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45))
#> Warning: Removed 51 rows containing non-finite outside the scale range
#> (`stat_boxplot()`).


# or just use terra::rasterize() + terra::boxplot():
y <- rasterize(v, r, "NAME_2")
boxplot(r,y)


Created on 2024-08-27 with reprex v2.1.1

Extremely nice suggestion. I was able to reproduce it using the terra sample files. However, I got an error using my own shape and raster file. > # extract, include names from vector attributes

e <- extract(r,v)
Error in h(simpleError(msg, call)) :
Fehler bei der Auswertung des Argumentes 'x' bei der Methodenauswahl für Funktion 'addAttrToGeom': coords must be a two-column matrix


extract(r, v)
Error in h(simpleError(msg, call)) :
Fehler bei der Auswertung des Argumentes 'x' bei der Methodenauswahl für Funktion 'addAttrToGeom': coords must be a two-column matrix


I see my shapefile varies from the terra sample. so e<-extract(r,v) or rasterize() was not successful > v Simple feature collection with 12 features and 14 fields Geometry type: MULTIPOLYGON Dimension: XY, XYZ Bounding box: xmin: 2485410 ymin: 1075268 xmax: 2833842 ymax: 1295934 z_range: zmin: 0 zmax: 0 Projected CRS: CH1903+ / LV95 # A tibble: 12 × 15 RegionNumm RegionName Unterregio Unterreg_1 ObjNummer Version Shape_Leng Shape_Area DERegionNa FRRegionNa ITRegionNa DEBioBedeu         –

I'm afraid you'd need to provide a fully  reproducible example along with datasets for less generic answer.  From your last comment you also seem to have an sf object from sf::st_read() and not SpatVector that you'd get from terra::vect().  By "terra or sf + stars" I meant use either  terra OR use sf with starts. But if it's about multipolygon shapes, you can separate those to polygons with terra::disagg() .

How shoulld I read in  my shapefile correctly, not with read_sf? is there a vector function?

v <- read_sf("......N2020_Revision_BiogeoRegion.shp")
str(v)
sf [12 × 15] (S3: sf/tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
$ RegionNumm: num [1:12] 1 2 2 2 2 3 3 4 5 5 ...
$ Unterregio: num [1:12] 11 21 22 23 24 31 32 41 51 52 ..
$ Shape_Leng: num [1:12] 725117 334364
.. ..$ : num [1:23632, 1:2] 2641684 264
..$ :List of 1
..- attr(*, "class")= chr [1:3] "XY" "MULTIPOLYGON" "sfg"


attr(*, "sf_column")= chr "geometry"
attr(*, "agr")= Factor w/ 3 levels "constant","aggregate",


just like in my answer, v <- vect("yourshapefilepath.shp")

Further question. What do you mean by ID. e$NAME_2 <- v$NAME_2[e$ID] In my shapefile I have the names:  names       : RegionNumm RegionName Unterregio Unterreg_1 ObjNummer    Version Shape_Leng Shape_Area DERegionNa FRRegionNa (and 4 more)
type        :                         You have selected NAME_2, I will select "Unterregio". In your file I see ID_1, ID_2 as further names. I am not sure what ID is in your example?

ID column in resulting frame added by extract() to indicate the used polygon, you can check ?terra:::extract  for details.  For the rest, please edit your question so the issues you face would be reproducible for others, starting from loading libraries and actual minimal code that would reproduce the failure at our end (my answer does not load raster,  yet you have a RasterLayer ). And of course we would also need datasets to run  your code. More on MRE - https://stackoverflow.com/collectives/r-language/articles/76995406/how-to-write-a-good-r-question-with-a-reproducible-example  .

Many thanks. Yes I fully understand the advice. I am still struggling around providing a MRE based on my specific shapefile. There is already a MRE based on terra example files, and I do not see any difference compared to my shapefile.  Up to now I think that I have z coordinates in addition to the MRE, so I got a warning when loading it.   Probably loading the shapefile properly would solve the extract() error.
Load shp file

v <- vect("C:/Users/…._BiogeoRegion.shp")
Warning message:
[vect] Z coordinates ignored
str(v)
S4 class 'SpatVector' [package "terra"]

